# using doctrine and querybuilder, between two date

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to retrieve some data using queryBuilder, the condition is to use a datetime field on parent table and pass it to where condition, the child table have two date start and end, the whole condition is to select parent row depend on date between the two date in child table
the code is:

```
$qb->select('parent,child')
                ->from($this->class, 'parent')
                ->innerJoin('parent.childTable', 'child')
                //other join
                // and where


                //CONDITION  -> startdate <= $date AND enddate >= $date
                $betweenDates = $qb->expr()->andX( 
                    $qb->expr()->gt("child.dateStart", "parent.datetime"),
                    $qb->expr()->lt("child.dateEnd", "parent.datetime")
                );

                //CONDITION 4 -> enddate == NULL
                $endDateNull = $qb->expr()->isNull( 'child.dateEnd');
                $dates = $qb->expr()->orX($betweenDates, $endDateNull);

                 // take care of dateEnd if it's null
                $qb->expr()->andX($dates);
```

the problem is the where condition not work and the select still give me childs not respect date condition
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check Symfony's profiler, to get final SQL query that was executed. Then verify what's different in the query from what you expected it to be. It should give you a hint where to look.

Comment: Is this complete code? You're missing adding your final expression (last line in your submission) to query: `$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->andX($dates));`